# How to plot 1-Sigma Prediction Interval for scipy.odr

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, regression

When using an orthogonal distance regression (`scipy.odr`) with a log function, what is the correct way to plot 1-sigma prediction interval?

I have tried several different approaches (including from several SO posts), but with the log function, the intervals appear to be far too wide:

[image: regression with incorrect CI]

I was expecting it to look closer to this (homebrew logged linear regression):
[image]

Here is my code (including input data):

```py
from scipy.odr import ODR, Model, RealData
from matplotlib.pyplot import subplots, savefig
from numpy import log10, array, linspace


def log_func(beta, x):
    """
    * Log function for fitting using ODR
    """
    # logarithmic, m * log(x) + c
    return beta[0] * log10(x) + beta[1]


def plot_shed_curve(x_data, y_data, x_err, y_err, path):
    """
    * Fit curve using ODR and plot
    """
    # make function into Model instance (either log or linear)
    model = Model(log_func)

    # make data into RealData instance
    data = RealData(x_data, y_data, sx=x_err, sy=y_err)

    # initialise the ODR instance
    out = ODR(data, model, beta0=[-0.89225534, 59.09509794]).run()

    # pretty print the output
    out.pprint()

    # fit model using ODR params
    xn = linspace(min(x_data), max(x_data), 1000)
    yn = log_func(out.beta, xn)

    # create a figure to draw on and add a subplot
    fig, ax = subplots(1)

    # plot y calculated from px against de-logged x
    ax.plot(xn, yn, '#EC472F', label='Orthogonal Distance Regression (log)')

    # prepare parameters for confidence interval curves
    nstd = 1. # to draw 1-sigma intervals
    popt_up = out.beta + nstd * out.sd_beta
    popt_dw = out.beta - nstd * out.sd_beta

    # calculate y values for 1 sigma
    fit_up = log_func(popt_up, xn)
    fit_dw = log_func(popt_dw, xn)

    # plot 1 sigma
    ax.plot(xn, fit_up, '#0076D4', dashes=[9, 4.5], label='1 Sigma Prediction limit (68%)', linewidth=0.8)
    ax.plot(xn, fit_dw, '#0076D4', dashes=[9, 4.5], linewidth=0.8)

    # plot points and error bars
    ax.plot(x_data, y_data, 'k.', label='Age Control Points', markersize=3.5)
    ax.errorbar(x_data, y_data, ecolor='k', xerr=x_err, yerr=y_err, fmt=" ", linewidth=0.5, capsize=0)

    # labels, extents etc.
    ax.set_ylim(0, 60)
    ax.set_xlabel('Mean R-Value')
    ax.set_ylabel('Age (ka)')
    ax.set_title('Orthogonal Distance Regression and confidence limits')

    # configure legend
    ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0.99, 0.99), borderaxespad=0., frameon=False)

    # export the figure
    savefig(path)


# load data from Pyrenees curve
x_data = array([54.034,57.601,61.934,59.234,51.135,57.802,49.502,48.602,47.202,46.603,46.904,51.638,55.372,51.905,53.072,42.904,42.705,39.971,39.671,38.905,52.140,49.506,53.507,41.950,23.409,26.477,25.811,40.584,45.152,45.820,45.820,41.585,40.084,45.487,40.318,38.451,45.488,42.920,46.755,45.955,48.857,47.223,51.025,47.790,48.224,50.092,48.124,49.258,47.524,48.836,59.836,49.603])
y_data = array([12.866,12.436,4.138,5.285,11.740,8.944,13.828,13.600,14.761,15.644,15.982,12.130,8.714,12.178,11.783,20.982,20.609,22.634,23.234,23.858,10.967,11.988,11.987,21.307,51.862,43.874,42.212,20.431,17.226,17.374,17.453,20.949,22.503,18.887,22.052,24.974,18.005,19.417,18.157,18.720,16.550,16.414,15.022,16.475,16.699,16.452,16.406,15.151,17.410,16.924,8.673,17.910])
x_err  = array([0.65,0.67,0.65,0.71,0.49,0.73,1.04,1.18,0.91,0.89,0.94,0.95,0.76,0.9,0.99,0.99,1.07,0.94,0.86,0.94,1.41,1.38,1.09,1.21,0.98,1.02,1.12,1.06,0.92,0.98,1.02,1.2,1.03,1.22,1.1,1.15,1.05,1.44,1.26,1.34,1.07,0.68,1.01,1.09,1.22,0.82,1.09,0.76,1.05,0.82,0.74,0.87])
y_err  = array([1.071,1.014,0.341,0.446,0.959,0.821,1.2,1.614,1.49,1.52,1.437,1.131,0.838,1.44,1.24,3.91,3.292,3.393,3.969,3.371,1.972,1.734,2.856,4.633,4.171,3.524,3.388,1.659,1.389,1.417,1.434,1.693,1.815,1.516,2.267,2.002,1.448,1.557,1.456,1.502,1.331,1.322,1.207,1.327,1.336,2.692,2.592,2.704,2.352,2.713,1.901,4.756])

# plot the curve
plot_shed_curve(x_data, y_data, x_err, y_err, 'pyrenees.png')
```

Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combining the answers from from [Arne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13014172/arne)'s comment, alongside information from other sources, here is the solution:

```py
from scipy.stats import t
from scipy.odr import ODR, Model, RealData
from matplotlib.pyplot import subplots, savefig
from numpy import log10, array, linspace, zeros, sqrt

def prediction_interval(func, dfdp, x, y, yerr, signif, popt, pcov):
    """
    * Calculate Preduction Intervals
    *  adapted from Extraterrestrial Physics pdf
    *
    *  func    : function that we are using
    *  dfdp    : derivatives of that function (calculated using sympy.diff)
    *  x       : the x values (calculated using numpy.linspace)
    *  y       : the y values (calculated by passing the ODR parameters and x to func)
    *  y_err   : the maximum residual on the y axis
    *  signif  : the significance value (68., 95. and 99.7 for 1, 2 and 3 sigma respectively)
    *  popt    : the ODR parameters for the fit, calculated using scipy.odr.run()
    *  pcov    : the covariance matrix for the fit, calculated using scipy.odr.run()
    """
    # get number of fit parameters and data points
    np = len(popt)
    n = len(x)

    # convert provided value to a significance level (e.g. 95. -> 0.05), then calculate alpha
    alpha = 1. - (1 - signif / 100.0) / 2

    # student’s t test
    tval = t.ppf(alpha, n - np)

    # process covarianvce matrix and derivatives
    d = zeros(n)
    for j in range(np):
        for k in range(np):
            d += dfdp[j] * dfdp[k] * pcov[j,k]

    # return prediction band offset for a new measurement
    return tval * sqrt(yerr**2 + d)


def log_func(beta, x):
    """
    * Log function for fitting using ODR
    """
    return beta[0] * log10(x) + beta[1]


def plot_shed_curve(x_data, y_data, x_err, y_err):
    """
    * Fit curve using ODR and plot
    """
    # make function into Model instance (either log or linear)
    model = Model(log_func)

    # make data into RealData instance
    data = RealData(x_data, y_data, sx=x_err, sy=y_err)

    # initialise the ODR instance
    out = ODR(data, model, beta0=[-0.89225534, 59.09509794]).run()

    # fit model using ODR params
    xn = linspace(min(x_data), max(x_data), 1000)
    yn = log_func(out.beta, xn)

    # calculate curve and confidence bands
    pl1 = prediction_interval(log_func, [log10(xn), 1], xn, yn, max(out.eps), 68., out.beta, out.cov_beta)
    pl2 = prediction_interval(log_func, [log10(xn), 1], xn, yn, max(out.eps), 95., out.beta, out.cov_beta)

    # create a figure to draw on and add a subplot
    fig, ax = subplots(1)

    # plot y calculated from px against de-logged x (and 1 and 2 sigma prediction intervals)
    ax.plot(xn, yn, '#EC472F', label='Orthogonal Distance Regression (log)')
    ax.plot(xn, yn + pl1, '#0076D4', dashes=[9, 4.5], label=f'Prediction limit (68%)', linewidth=0.8)
    ax.plot(xn, yn - pl1, '#0076D4', dashes=[9, 4.5], linewidth=0.8)
    ax.plot(xn, yn + pl2, '0.5', dashes=[9, 3], label='2 Sigma Prediction Limit (95%)', linewidth=0.5)
    ax.plot(xn, yn - pl2, '0.5', dashes=[9, 3], linewidth=0.5)

    # plot points and error bars
    ax.plot(x_data, y_data, 'k.', label='Age Control Points', markersize=3.5)
    ax.errorbar(x_data, y_data, ecolor='k', xerr=x_err, yerr=y_err, fmt=" ", linewidth=0.5, capsize=0)

    # labels, extents etc.
    ax.set_ylim(0, 60)
    ax.set_xlabel('Mean R-Value')
    ax.set_ylabel('Age (ka)')
    ax.set_title('Orthogonal Distance Regression and Prediction Limits')

    # configure legend
    ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0.99, 0.99), borderaxespad=0., frameon=False)

    # export the figure
    savefig('pyrenees.png')


# load data from Pyrenees curve
x_data = array([54.034,57.601,61.934,59.234,51.135,57.802,49.502,48.602,47.202,46.603,46.904,51.638,55.372,51.905,53.072,42.904,42.705,39.971,39.671,38.905,52.140,49.506,53.507,41.950,23.409,26.477,25.811,40.584,45.152,45.820,45.820,41.585,40.084,45.487,40.318,38.451,45.488,42.920,46.755,45.955,48.857,47.223,51.025,47.790,48.224,50.092,48.124,49.258,47.524,48.836,59.836,49.603])
y_data = array([12.866,12.436,4.138,5.285,11.740,8.944,13.828,13.600,14.761,15.644,15.982,12.130,8.714,12.178,11.783,20.982,20.609,22.634,23.234,23.858,10.967,11.988,11.987,21.307,51.862,43.874,42.212,20.431,17.226,17.374,17.453,20.949,22.503,18.887,22.052,24.974,18.005,19.417,18.157,18.720,16.550,16.414,15.022,16.475,16.699,16.452,16.406,15.151,17.410,16.924,8.673,17.910])
x_err  = array([0.65,0.67,0.65,0.71,0.49,0.73,1.04,1.18,0.91,0.89,0.94,0.95,0.76,0.9,0.99,0.99,1.07,0.94,0.86,0.94,1.41,1.38,1.09,1.21,0.98,1.02,1.12,1.06,0.92,0.98,1.02,1.2,1.03,1.22,1.1,1.15,1.05,1.44,1.26,1.34,1.07,0.68,1.01,1.09,1.22,0.82,1.09,0.76,1.05,0.82,0.74,0.87])
y_err  = array([1.071,1.014,0.341,0.446,0.959,0.821,1.2,1.614,1.49,1.52,1.437,1.131,0.838,1.44,1.24,3.91,3.292,3.393,3.969,3.371,1.972,1.734,2.856,4.633,4.171,3.524,3.388,1.659,1.389,1.417,1.434,1.693,1.815,1.516,2.267,2.002,1.448,1.557,1.456,1.502,1.331,1.322,1.207,1.327,1.336,2.692,2.592,2.704,2.352,2.713,1.901,4.756])

# plot the curve
plot_shed_curve(x_data, y_data, x_err, y_err)
```

To calculated the derivatives for the log equation (`[log10(x), 1]`, hard-coded into the above), I used [sympy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html):

```py
from sympy import symbols, diff
from sympy.codegen.cfunctions import log10 as slog10

# use sympy to calculate derivatives for each parameter (a and b)
a, b, x = symbols('a b x')
diffs = [diff(a * slog10(x) + b, a), diff(a * slog10(x) + b, b)]
print (diffs)
```

Here is the result:
[image: resulting curve with prediction limits]

Comment: If you could possibly list your 'other sources', I'd be grateful.

Comment: In the site on Arne's comment,  I used https://www.astro.rug.nl/software/kapteyn/kmpfittutorial.html#confidence-and-prediction-intervals and https://www.astro.rug.nl/software/kapteyn/EXAMPLES/kmpfit_ODRparabola_confidence.py. The main document that I used aside from that one was a document called "Mathematical, Numerical, and Statistical Methods in Extraterrestrial Physics Lecture Notes 2017-2018" - Someone sent this to me via email so I don't have a link (and can't find one), but you can see it here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/48myp25gonz2sf3/statistics.pdf?dl=1 . I hope that helps!

Comment: I _think_ what you're showing there are the confidence intervals for the prediction of y for existing values of x, rather than the predictions intervals for new predictions of y from a new experiment / observation of x.

Comment: Interesting - thatks for the feedback, do you know how to remedy that?

Answer (score 0):

Computing a prediction band for orthogonal distance regression (ODR) is not as straightforward as it is for ordinary least squares regression. With ODR, there are errors in both x- and y-direction, which you both need to take into account. That's why `popt_up = out.beta + nstd * out.sd_beta` will not give you a proper prediction band.

It should be possible to compute a prediction band from the covariance matrix that `scipy.odr` returns, but I don't know if this has been implemented in any convenient Python function yet.

Comment: Thankyou, that's very useful to know - could you point me in the right direction for how I might go about calculating from the covariance matrix?

Comment: You're welcome. For a good discussion of this issue, see the sections "Fitting data when both variables have uncertainties" and "Confidence- and prediction intervals" in this tutorial: 
http://www.astro.rug.nl/software/kapteyn/kmpfittutorial.html.